# How to add date in Windows 10 to system clock

Tags: windows

How to add date like day-month-year hour:minute to system clock in tray? I was looking in the settings, but nowhere has such an option. All the time shows me only an hour.

Comment: That's how it is by default... it is on mine?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the toolbar width / icon size. If the icons are small (the toolbar narrow), the date won't fit, so it shows only the time. When you set the large icons or extend the toolbar, it will show the date as well.

This question should be moved to superuser.com

Comment: No problem, @lukassz.